# Unable to push commits

Tags: git, github, branch, semantic-ui

I am trying push a recent commit to my central repository on github, but I am denied access to my own repository. What can I do to change or override settings?

```
frameworks/Semantic-UI$ sudo git push
Username for 'https://github.com': team@everest.software
Password for 'https://team@everest.software@github.com':
remote: Permission to Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI.git denied to everest-software.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI.git/': The 
requested URL returned error: 403
```

Answer (score 1):

As username for a GitHub repository should not be an email address, but an actual GitHub account user name.

> `Username for 'https://github.com':` <del>`team@everest.software`</del> `aUSername`

That is clearly apparent when one [join GitHub](https://github.com/join):

[image]

---

Second, that username should match the one owning the repository you are pushing to:

```
Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI.git
```

I will assume your GitHub username account is *not* Semantic-Org, which means:

- you are not the owner (and probably not a collaborator) on Semantic-UI.git repository
- you cannot push directly to a repository you don't own

If you want to push back to `Semantic-UI.git`, you need to **fork** that repository first.

See "[**Fork a repo**](https://help.github.com/articles/fork-a-repo/)".