# Can't push git changes to Github

Tags: git, github, ssh

I am trying to push changes to github and I am encountering the following problem.

```
ts/Central-Repo/everest-web$ git push
Enter passphrase for key '/Users/developer/.ssh/id_rsa':
ERROR: Permission to meanjs/mean.git denied to everest-software.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

What command or change in file path would fix this problem and allow me to talk to my github repo again?

Comment: It seems you don't have the correct access rights... Or the repository doesn't exist!

Comment: How do you change access rights? This repository is already on github, I am just pushing changes so it must exist.

Comment: You own the repo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
meanjs/mean.git denied to everest-software.
```

As I just answered to [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51485997/6309), you cannot push to a repository you do not own (through https, as before, or ssh as now)

`everest-software` does now own `meanjs/mean.git`. The organization `meanjs` does.

You need to **[fork the repo first](https://help.github.com/articles/fork-a-repo/)**.
Then clone the fork.
Add, commit, and push back to it.

Comment: Is there a way to fork the repo, clone it, and then add, commit, push my copy to my own personal repo and put my name on it or is that against the license rules?

Comment: If you change the name of the forked repo, it is no longer a fork. You can simply create a new empty repository, change the origin URL of your current clone, and push to that new empty repo, which you own, and that you can name however you want.